# Ignore throw $break in Chrome JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome

I'm using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) in a web app, and I'd like to break when exceptions are thrown (including handled ones). However, I don't want to break on exception used for flow control, specifically the `throw $break` pattern used in Prototype's `each` implementation.

```
function detect(iterator, context) {
  var result;
  this.each(function(value, index) {
    if (iterator.call(context, value, index)) {
      result = value;
      throw $break; // I want to ignore this one
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Does anyone know how to get Chrome's debugger to ignore specific exceptions? Or to get it to ignore exceptions thrown from specific lines? Or even to get it to not break in specific files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain there is no such feature. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-exceptions.html), which seems fairly complete, doesn't mention it. Also, the Chrome Developer Tool uses the Remote Debugging protocol, whose [Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/protocol/debugger.html#command-setPauseOnExceptions) command does not have a "file" parameter. That said, I have not grokked the source code.

Getting Chrome's debugger to ignore specific exceptions or files would also help when working with jQuery. It catches and re-throws any exception in an event callback (search for "resolveWith"), making the message in the console essentially useless. jQuery throws and catches exceptions internally all the time, so breaking on all exceptions produces too much noise.